# Is my row calculation of row echelon form correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was directed by a community member to a resource on how to calculate the row echelon form of a matrix [here](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/~spiegler/teaching/Spring_05/normal.pdf). The resource says:

```
First we wish to put A into reduced row echelon form. There are several ways to do those (and
thus several matrices P), but here is one possible way: (calculation next)
```

So, I  understand that a given matrix can have multiple row echelon forms.

To continue my self-study of linear algebra further, I looked at the example on [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Reduce-a-Matrix-to-Row-Echelon-Form).
It gives a simple 3x3 matrix and shows how to calculate the row echelon form. Fair enough.

As in wikihow, the given matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the row echelon form is this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
**However, my answer is different and I am not sure if it is correct**

#### My calculation on the same matrix:

Attempting to get all zeros under $A_1_1$ as:

$R_2$ - $R_1$ ->   $R_2$
$(3\times R_1$) - $R_3$ -> $R_3$
So, the matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Attempting to get all zeroes under $A_2_2$ as:

$R_2$ + $R_3$ -> $R_3$
So the matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The only difference is that I have a $2$ in bottom right and wikihow has $-2$.
**Is it correct ?**

Comment: yes, there are multiple echelon forms. For example you can continue multiplying third row by (-1) and get the other answer. Or you can add any multiple of a lower row to an upper row and still keep the echelon form. (What is unique is the `reduced row echelon form` where you insist pivots must be 1 and all other elements a pivot column should be zero.)

Comment: @Maesumi is there a rule that $3XR_3 - R_1$ -> $R_3$ because $R_3$ was the first operand ????

Comment: You can use the addition of rows $m R_n \pm R_k$  however you like (so long as $n\ne k$). Here to get zero you  can use $3R_1-R_3$ or $R_3-3R_1$. The typical standard notation in text books is to use $mR_n + R_k$.

Comment: @Maesumi so my answer is correct :) Plus, there was a mistake in WIkiHow which I had to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting different answers because you're subtracting $R_3$ from $3 R_1$.  Usually, you subtract $3 R_1$ from $R_3$ (you can add or subtract rows, but you're changing the sign on $R_3$ here:  we often choose to do it this way because adding or subtracting a multiple of a row keeps the determinant the same).

So, to get Wikihow's answer, you should have taken $R_3 - 3R_1 \to R_3$ instead.  This also explains the sign flip, since $R_3 - 3R_1 = - ( 3R_1 - R_3 )$.